# Longer send timeouts means longer delays too?

Tags: .net, performance, wcf, timeout

I'm getting frequent send timeout errors possibly from too much load on the database and the bulkiness of data. If sending the reply to a wcf request takes up 3 mins, then setting the timeout to 3+ mins would be enough.

**But does that also mean that port 80 will be busy for 3 mins and won't be sending other replies until the current one finishes?**

If that is the case then I would need to optimize my WCF and rebuild my indexes as well as probably do a few upgrades to the hardware of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the WCF threading system does have a specific number of concurrent threads/processes it can handle based on your service throttling configuration and instance mode.  It does not block port 80 for a single request so it will not hamper that; however, if you have a lot of simultaneous users, it could bog down the system if they are all running long service operation calls and using all your threads.

You should still take a look at optimizing your service/db. What are your normal clients using it for? If it is web, then obviously 3 mins is way too long to wait. At least I know I would be gone if something took that long!

As the phrase goes, there are many ways to skin a cat and without knowing your full system it would be hard to pick the single one to use, so here are some options (throwing more hardware at it should be last resort):

From a DB perspective, if getting the data is taking a long time, maybe you should look at possibly de-normalizing/pre-crunching the data to make it easier to retrieve.

From a service perspective there are ways to at least give control back to client so it can continue processing while waiting for the service operation to complete.

1. Use duplex calling with callbacks to client when finished
2. Use one way requests with an Id, with a manual client 'check for complete'
3. Use MSMQ to process and keep results for client to check when complete

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would block port 80 even if there are free threads. I wanted to increase the timeouts to fix the failed replies while I work on the optimizations.